# are all problems solvable given infinite time?

Tags: turing-machines

Given a turing machine which has unlimited memory and time, can it solve all problems or are there a class of problems that cannot be solved even with unbounded power.

Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: What does it mean to "solve a problem in infinite time"? If the machine runs forever, it never returns an answer.

Comment: The difficulty with "unlimited memory and time" is that, in general, no matter how long you wait for a Turning machine to complete, you can never tell whether it will complete eventually if you just wait a bit longer, or if it has disappeared up its own source code and you will never hear from it again. If you could see *all of time* at once then you would know, but then you have created a Turing *oracle*, not a Turing *machine*.

Comment: @gandalf61 So for the halting program, I cannot just run the program? Given I have unlimited time. Interesting

Comment: Be very very very careful about infinity, a beast that is really out of the ordinary. In fact, we should say "inifities", since one kind of infinity might be vastly different from another kind of inifinity. Even with the simple kinds of "infinities", it might be still tricky and difficult to reason about them.

Comment: For example, it is actually not easy to understand or explain the meaning of "in unlimited time" scientifically at all. It is only deceiving that it sounds so obvious.